# How can I assign an id column in SQL query that merges geometries?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a layer that consists of a number of features.  Each features is a line segment and has an attribute named zone_name which takes one of 7 values.  What I want to do is to use the atlas generation to print out a map for each zone (which consists of multiple features/lines) but (assuming I understand things correctly) the atlas generator iterates over all features in the layer -- first time I tried I got a large number of very small maps ;)

After a bit of research I came up with this:

```
SELECT zone_name,
     ST_Multi(ST_Collect(f.the_geom)) as singlegeom
     FROM (SELECT layer_name, (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom As the_geom
                FROM
                tracks_master, layers where feature_gid = gid ) As f
GROUP BY zone_name
```

in the database manager SQL window.  When I run the query it produces a table with a single feature for each value of zone_name.  The only problem is that there is no integer id field so I can not load this as a layer.  I.e. when I select "load as layer" there isn't anything valid to put in "column with unique integer values".

There must be a simple way of doing this but my SQL isn't up to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id, 
     zone_name,
     ST_Multi(ST_Collect(f.the_geom)) as singlegeom
     FROM (SELECT layer_name, (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom As the_geom
                FROM
                tracks_master, layers where feature_gid = gid ) As f
GROUP BY zone_name
```

Comment: And indeed it does!  Thank, I keep forgetting about functions.